# anyone using perfectomobile for testing?

Tags: android

I have completed my first android app and am trying to test it on 'perfectomobile' web site which allows download to actual phones.   I have selected the HTC Wildfire which is said to haqve Android 2.1 (Eclair) os.   I am using Eclipse and have exported the app which is targeted to Android 2.1 update 1.  Downloaded it to the sd card on the Wildfire and when I click on it in the Anddev list on the phone screen I get the 'Parse error' message.

The app runs fine on the emulator on my pc?   Is the parse error referring to something in the XML files or might it be in the code?

I've done a lot of googling re parse error without enlightment so I am wondering if anyone on here can suggest how to track down the item causing the error.
Thanks
Ron

Answer (score 2):

I also develop for Android and have confronted similar issues myself.

the lesson here is this (and believe me I have learned the hard way...) - TESTING APPS ON SIMULATORS IS NEVER ENOUGH!
You always run into problems of license, OS computability, byte order etc...

Sorry I can't help with this specific problem but keep using the perfeco mobile platform. It's the most advanced remote mobile testing solution that actually lets you access REAL phones and tablets and also the most affordable (they have a specific "[Android testing](http://perfectomobile.com/portal/cms/Services/android)" cloud package)

Best of luck!!!

guido

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement guido.   It would be useful toknow if this 'parsing' error is generated just by the xml files so if anyone reading this knows please repsond.

Answer (score 1):

The good thing about devices in a mobile cloud is that the exact same device is accessible from anywhere in the world. So if you're doing hand-offs in labs working across several timezones, it makes sense. Perfecto has a private cloud option that keeps devices isolated from others. They are working on a solution for iOS that doesn't involve jail-breaking.

One team in HP (mine) created a framework that creates automated test scripts such that they can be used during the first successful build. This can occur because keywords and label text (in various written languages) are specified in spreadsheets (based on the same specs that developers use). We've taught the framework fancy logic to look up objects in the app. This means that testers don't need to wait until apps are built, and be testing on apps several sprints behind. This changes the whole relationship between testers and developers. Simpler specs means non-technical business people can automate GUI-level UAT scripts. And one set of test specs can be used to test both web and mobile. Otherwise, mobile and web test teams create two different sets of scripts - on for mobile and one for traditional web.